# What is the formula to find the different unlabeled trees that can be formed from a given set of nodes?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I am just doing a research on a project and came across a problem. I would be very grateful if anybody could help me out with this. Consider the figure below:

[image]

Two dots joined by a line results in only one diagram, three dots joined by single lines also results in one figure no matter how you join the dots, the result is the same. But as we increase the dots there are different possibilities, as seen with four dots.

Is there a formula for counting the number of unlabeled trees that can be formed from a set of nodes?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem so I won't answer directly. However, to point you the right way, it sounds like you're talking about something related to "random graphs."

Comment: Also probably more suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/ seen as it is what is the formula? Rather than how do I program it?

Comment: Why does three dots not result in two figures?  Is the rule that the first dot can only have one line coming out of it?

Comment: Why was it closed? Shouldn't it be moved to math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is non-isomorphic graph count problem.

For general case, there are 2^(<sup>n</sup><sub>2</sub>) non-isomorphic graphs on `n` vertices where (<sup>n</sup><sub>2</sub>) is binomial coefficient "n above 2".

However that may give you also some extra graphs depending on which graphs are considered the same (you also were not 100% clear which graphs do apply).

[See this paper.](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2F~adamchik%2F21-127%2Flectures%2Fgraphs_2_print.pdf&ei=SsFiTdToFM2cOoXdhO0N&usg=AFQjCNH4n-KrVluc7_2H83H3WL8c98cEnw&sig2=lWDGaFBiwY7J0fFN1NHDKA)
[And this article on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html).

EDIT: In case you want to count labeled trees only the formula is `n^(n-2)`.

[Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

Comment: You probably want the number of trees with n unlabeled nodes: http://oeis.org/A000055

Comment: As stated by mzabsky above, the number of spanning trees of a complete graph is given by n^(n-2) (Cayley?). In Mma 7 there is a command `NumberOfSpanningTrees` in the Combinatorica package which might be of some use.  Possibly updated in Mma8.  For example Needs["Combinatorica`"];
NumberOfSpanningTrees[CompleteGraph[4]] gives 16 (as expected). You may benefit by looking at Mathematica/Combinatorica.

Comment: The formula $2^\binom{n}{2}$ counts the number of *labeled graphs* on n vertices. The formula $n^{n-2}$ counts the number of *labeled trees* on n vertices. OP is asking for *unlabeled* (i.e. nonisomorphic) trees on n vertices, which is significantly harder. So far, no closed form is known.

Comment: n^(n-2) is the formula for "labeled" trees not unlabeled trees

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments, your question can be phrased as determining the number of unlabeled trees on n vertices. Notice this differs significantly from the question of counting *labeled trees* (of which there are n^{n-2}) or *labeled graphs* (of which there are 2^\binom{n}{2}).

The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences has a lot of good data about this problem (including code to generate the sequence): https://oeis.org/A000055. In particular, it gives a generating function A(x) for these numbers, which is the best solution known to date (from a mathematician's perspective):

A(x) = 1 + T(x) - T^2(x)/2 + T(x^2)/2, where T(x) = x + x^2 + 2x^3 + ...

If you are not familiar with generating functions, think of it as a carefully designed polynomial whose coefficients form the desired sequence. That is, the coefficient of x^n in this polynomial would be the number of unlabeled trees on n vertices.

As a final plug, you may find this reference useful: http://austinmohr.com/work/trees. It gives some counts and images for trees of up to ten vertices.